# Why does Keras BatchNorm produce different output than PyTorch?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, pytorch, batch-normalization

Torch：'1.9.0+cu111'

Tensorflow-gpu：'2.5.0'

I came across a strange thing, when using the Batch Normal layer of tensorflow 2.5 and the BatchNorm2d layer of Pytorch 1.9 to calculate the same Tensor , and the results were **quite different** (TensorFlow is close to 1, Pytorch is close to 0).I thought at first it was the difference between the momentum and epsilon , but after changing them to the same, the result was the same.

```
from torch import nn
import torch
x = torch.ones((20, 100, 35, 45))
a = nn.Sequential(
            # nn.Conv2d(512, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), padding=0, bias=True),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(100)
        )
b = a(x)

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
x = tf.ones((20, 35, 45, 100))
a = keras.models.Sequential([
            # Conv2D(128, (1, 1), (1, 1), padding='same', use_bias=True),
            BatchNormalization()
        ])
b = a(x)
```

[image: The result of TensorFlow]

[image: The result of Pytorch]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Batchnormalization works differently in training and inference,

**During training** (i.e. when using `fit()` or when calling the layer/model with the argument `training=True`), the layer normalizes its output using the mean and standard deviation of the current batch of inputs. That is to say, for each channel being normalized, the layer returns

```
gamma * (batch - mean(batch)) / sqrt(var(batch) + epsilon) + beta
```

where:

- **epsilon** is small constant (configurable as part of the constructor arguments)
- **gamma** is a learned scaling factor (initialized as 1), which can be disabled by passing scale=False to the constructor.
- **beta** is a learned offset factor (initialized as 0), which can be disabled by passing center=False to the constructor.

**During inference** (i.e. when using `evaluate()` or `predict()` or when calling the layer/model with the argument `training=False` (which is the default), the layer normalizes its output using a moving average of the mean and standard deviation of the batches it has seen during training. That is to say, it returns

```
gamma * (batch - self.moving_mean) / sqrt(self.moving_var + epsilon) + beta.
```

`self.moving_mean` and `self.moving_var` are non-trainable variables that are updated each time the layer in called in training mode, as such:

```py
    moving_mean = moving_mean * momentum + mean(batch) * (1 - momentum)
    moving_var = moving_var * momentum + var(batch) * (1 - momentum)
```

ref: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/BatchNormalization

If you run the pytorch batchnorm in `eval` mode, you get close results (the rest of the discrepancy comes from the different internal implementation, parameter choices, etc.),

```
from torch import nn
import torch
x = torch.ones((1, 2, 2, 2))
a = nn.Sequential(
            # nn.Conv2d(512, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), padding=0, bias=True),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(2)
        )
a.eval()
b = a(x)
print(b)
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
x = tf.ones((1, 2, 2, 2))
a = keras.models.Sequential([
            # Conv2D(128, (1, 1), (1, 1), padding='same', use_bias=True),
            BatchNormalization()
        ])
b = a(x)
print(b)
```

`out:`

```
tensor([[[[1.0000, 1.0000],
          [1.0000, 1.0000]],

         [[1.0000, 1.0000],
          [1.0000, 1.0000]]]], grad_fn=<NativeBatchNormBackward>)
tf.Tensor(
[[[[0.9995004 0.9995004]
   [0.9995004 0.9995004]]

  [[0.9995004 0.9995004]
   [0.9995004 0.9995004]]]], shape=(1, 2, 2, 2), dtype=float32)
```